# java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Tags: java

При запуске клиент-серверного приложения ЧАТА вылетает ошибка, указанная в заголовке

Первым делом запускаю Сервер, все ОК.
Потом запускаю клиент, ввожу свой логин через консоль, а при вводе сообщения вылетает ошибка и ссылается все на  `InputStream is = http.getInputStream();` 
Подсказали, что нужно решить этот вопрос через Firewall. Но я понятия не имею, как это сделать
Почитал другие ответы, ничего путевого для своей проблемы не нашел.

```
public class GetThread implements Runnable {
    private final Gson gson;
    private int n;

    public GetThread() {
        gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while ( ! Thread.interrupted()) {
                URL url = new URL(Utils.getURL() + "/get?from=" + n);
                HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                InputStream is = http.getInputStream();
                try {
                    byte[] buf = requestBodyToArray(is);
                    String strBuf = new String(buf, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

                    JsonMessages list = gson.fromJson(strBuf, JsonMessages.class);
                    if (list != null) {
                        for (Message m : list.getList()) {
                            System.out.println(m);
                            n++;
                        }
                    }
                } finally {
                    is.close();
                }

                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private byte[] requestBodyToArray(InputStream is) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buf = new byte[10240];
        int r;

        do {
            r = is.read(buf);
            if (r > 0) bos.write(buf, 0, r);
        } while (r != -1);

        return bos.toByteArray();
    }
}




public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            System.out.println("Enter your login: ");
            String login = scanner.nextLine();

            Thread th = new Thread(new GetThread());
            th.setDaemon(true);
            th.start();

            System.out.println("Enter your message: ");
            while (true) {
                String text = scanner.nextLine();
                if (text.isEmpty()) break;

                Message m = new Message(login, text);
                int res = m.send(Utils.getURL() + "/add");

                if (res != 200) { // 200 OK
                    System.out.println("HTTP error occured: " + res);
                    return;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            scanner.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Полный перечень ошибок :

> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect    at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)     at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)   at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)    at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)  at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)  at
>   sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)   at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)   at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)   at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.(HttpClient.java:242)   at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)  at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)  at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1220)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1156)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:984)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1564)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
>     at com.company.GetThread.run(GetThread.java:28)     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: недостаточно информации, добавьте код

Comment: Посмотрите в дебаге или сделайте вывод в консоль адреса, к которому обращается код: `Utils.getURL() + "/get?from=" + n` Проверьте, возможно ли открыть этот адрес браузером.